# Python: ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3af1af0a8008> in <module>
      1 for dataset in train_test_data:
----> 2     dataset.loc[ dataset['Age'] <= 16, 'Age'] = 0,
      3     dataset.loc[(dataset['Age'] > 16) & (dataset['Age'] <= 26), 'Age'] = 1,
      4     dataset.loc[(dataset['Age'] > 26) & (dataset['Age'] <= 36), 'Age'] = 2,
      5     dataset.loc[(dataset['Age'] > 36) & (dataset['Age'] <= 62), 'Age'] = 3,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    668 
    669         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 670         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    671 
    672     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1665                     # Exclude zero-len for e.g. boolean masking that is all-false
   1666                     raise ValueError(
-> 1667                         "cannot set using a multi-index "
   1668                         "selection indexer with a different "
   1669                         "length than the value"

ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`enter code here`
```

Getting above error on kaggle notebook
Python: ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: Remove the commas at the end of the lines

Comment: Thanks @azro .. working